# gdb debugger Error : "-var-create: Unable to create variable object"

Tags: c, gcc, gdb

I am Using Netbeans with C/C++ Plugin on  Windows 7 x86 System. I am getting Error when debugging the code. But when I run the code, it runs with out any problem.. As soon as I start debugging the code, it stops at 2-3 Lines before "main()" application.. And getting debugger error as follow :

```
(gdb) 
17^error,msg="-var-create: unable to create variable object"
(gdb) 
18^done,changelist=[]
(gdb) 
19^error,msg="-var-create: unable to create variable object"
(gdb) 
20^done,changelist=[]
(gdb) 
21^done,name="var3",numchild="4",value="{...}",type="const MyVar",has_more="0"
(gdb) 
24-var-show-attributes "var3"
.
.
.
.

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

I will appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its a bug in netbeans.
http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=205708

Try other versions.(Whats the version you are using,Can you please update it , it will be useful for others). Thanks